# Unable to remove password requirements for domain users group

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2016, domain-controller

I have little children (age 4 and 5) logging in to domain computers who need passwords as simple as "123".  I have done everything I can imagine to remove password requirements for them without any success.  **How can I disable all password complexity and rules enforcement for a specified user group?**

Things I have tried:

- Excluding the group from the default domain policy.
- Creating a specific policy with no password requirements applied to that user group only.
- Removing password complexity rules from the default domain policy group.

Nothing I do seems to enable me to create a new user with a super easy child password.

Help please and thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

The answer is to use a fine-grained password policy applied to the specific user group.

Steps:

1. Open Server Manager > Tools > Active Directory Administrative Center
2. Select your Domain > System > Password Settings Container
3. Click New > Password Settings
4. Choose your desired settings
5. Under "Directly Apples To", choose "Add", then add the desired groups
6. A) For new users:  Create a user with a password that follows the normal complexity requirements, then after the user is created and added to the correct group(s), change the password based on the modified requirements.

   B) For existing users:  Simply change the password based on the modified requirements.

Helpful Source:  [How to create a fine-grained password policy in AD](https://specopssoft.com/blog/create-fine-grained-password-policy-active-directory/)